# didSelectRowAtIndexPath for Custom label Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using this method to add an `UILabel` to my `UITableView` and its working fine, but I also need to create a method for selecting the row and save into an temp String.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 300, 30)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    label.text = [tableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Whitney-Light" size:20.0];
    return cell;
}
```

but its not working. It was working fine with when I was using cell.textLabel but not with the  custom label.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *lbltemp = cell1.textLabel;

    _parent.labelone.text = lbltemp.text;       
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create your own `UITableViewCell` subclass to allow you to get the reference to your label (and prevent you from creating multiple labels on the cell). Or you could use tags like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell = nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                         reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 300, 30)];
        label.tag = 123123;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    }

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:123123];
    label.text = [tableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Whitney-Light" size:20.0];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:123123];

    _parent.labelone.text = label.text;       
}
```

Your original code was adding a new label but then trying to get the text from the default label... It was also always creating a new cell and adding a new label to it which is quite wasteful.

Also, you shouldn't usually store text in the label, you should really to to your `tableArr` to get the text. The tag approach is more suited to updating the label when you reuse the cell or if you're letting the user edit the text (in a `UITextField`).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `cell1.textLabel` is not the label you created. It's simply the default Label created by the cell.

The solution could be:

Add a tag to the your label when you create your custom cell.

Say `label.tag=100;`

In `didSelectRow`,

Use

```
UILabel *lbltemp=(UILabel *)[cell1.contentView viewWithTag:100];
```

then `_parent.labelone.text=lbltemp.text; should` grab your text from that label.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's not working is that you're not referencing the custom label in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. The easiest way to get a reference to the custom label is using tags:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // Also, this is the proper way to use reuseIdentifier (your code is incorrect)
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10, 300, 30)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    label.text = [tableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Whitney-Light" size:20.0];
    label.tag = 1;

    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *customLabel = [cell viewWithTag:1];
    _parent.labelone.text = customLabel.text;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ([cell.contentView addSubview:label];_) you are creating your custom label and adding it as subview to cell's content view but in UILabel *lbltemp = cell1.textLabel; you are trying to access the default label of tableview cell .Add some identifier(like tag) to your label and access it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use default label and refuse from this workaround
just add

```
cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10,10, 300, 30);
```

Also it's better for memory to reuse cells as in Wain's answer

Answer (score 0):

use cell.indentationallevel or cell.indentationwidth