# How to get Tableview selected cell UILabels Value using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to get selected `cell` row label values. I have maintain multiple `label` values on `tableview` cell. whenever I selected the cell I need to get the values. i don't have much code, I am using below methods

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Have you enable multiple selection of UITableview?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902489/didselectrowatindexpath-for-custom-label-cell

Comment: Multiple touch not enabled @Jaimish

Comment: what you exactly want when you tap on the cell of tableview

Comment: tableview row click to get custom label value. I have used storyboard tablview with custom cells. On cell I used 4 UILabels whenever I click that row need to get label text values@Jaimish

Comment: Could you show us your `cellForRow...` method?

Comment: from that 4 Labels which labels's text you want? @Apple_Ajay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just add this code in your project..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
Simpletablecell *cell = (Simpletablecell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath]; // SimpletableCell is your cell you can add your cell here like UITableViewCell..
self.lbl1.text = cell.lbl3.text;// cell.lbl3 is a label of cell.
self.lbl2.text = cell.lbl4.text;// here only two labels values get you can get other labels also 
//......
//....
}
```

for more info visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356869/how-to-get-the-cell-label-text-values-from-a-selected-row-of-uitableview).

Comment: Awesome!@shahzaib maqbool

Comment: This works just fine but chances are you can do it a lot cheaper by accessing these values directly from your dataSource...

Answer (score 0):

Ok try to get cell on your didselect method as follow:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *lblValue = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:YourtagValueOfLabelinStoryboard];

    NSLog(@"Your Label value:%@",lblValue.text);
}
```

Comment: have given proper tag value to label in story board?

Comment: I did by another way bro. Thank you so much@Jaimish

Comment: Happy to help @Apple_Ajay